# python: Using quotes in the subprocess.popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying this however getting an error for following line of code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(r"/bin/date -s "%s" " % self.sysdate)
```

Error:

```
  File "date.py", line 12
    p = subprocess.Popen(r"/bin/date -s "%s" " % self.sysdate)
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have also tried:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(r'/bin/date -s "%s" ' % self.sysdate)
```

still got an error. Any help over this is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Subprocess prefers a list of strings for the program and its arguments. Try

```
subprocess.Popen(['/bin/date', '-s', '%s' % self.sysdate])
```

Comment: self.sysdate = 25 AUG 2012 2:50:00

Error:
File "date.py", line 12, in changedatelinux
    p = subprocess.Popen('/bin/date', '-s', '%s' % self.sysdate)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 589, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer

Comment: You forgot to make the arguments into a list... Add the `[]` around them.

Comment: Its a string, I am passing it to the constructor as Date('25 AUG 2012 2:50:00')

Comment: I meant the arguments to subprocess.Popen.

Answer (score 0):

You send the subprocess Popen args as list of strings. And moreover when you are spliting the string use the module function like `shlex.split`.

```
>>> date_str = '/bin/date -s "%s"' % '%HH:%MM'
>>> date_str
'/bin/date -s "%HH:%MM"'
>>> import shlex
>>> vals = shlex.split(date_str)
>>> vals
['/bin/date', '-s', '%HH:%MM']
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(vals)
```